# Как найти угол в градусах имея синус - python

Tags: python, тригонометрия

Я пишу игру на pygame и мне нужно найти угол.

```
sin = y/(math.sqrt(x*x+y*y))
```

sin - синус этого угла, как с помощью него найти сам угол?

Comment: Используйте math.asin

Comment: а в каких единицах эта функция принимает значение и в каких возвращает?

Comment: Возвращает в радианах. Можно перевестись в градусы с помощью math.degrees

Comment: а принимает в каких?

Comment: В каком смысле? Он принимает синус, т. е. от -1 до 1

Comment: извините, оговорился

Answer (score 1):

Если требуется узнать угол направления на точку *(x, y)*, всегда используйте [math.atan2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.atan2). Она решает задачу точнее и быстрее чем любая другая обратная тригонометрическая функция. Обратите внимание на обратный порядок аргументов:

```
angle_in_radians = math.atan2(y, x)
```

Радианы надо будет перевести в градусы:

```
angle_in_degrees = angle_in_radians * 180 / math.pi
```